# Converting int in string to letters;

Tags: c++, string, int

I am completely out of any ideas,

how to convert string that has some numbers to a string which will have as many letters as this number.

For example, if the user provides string like "**B5C5**" I would like to convert it to string looking like this "**BBBBBCCCCC**".

Is there any simple and convenient way to do this? I would be grateful for any clues. Thanks

Comment: you could use regex

Comment: I doubt there is any way you would regard as simple and convenient. Don't expect shortcuts, you just need to write the code. Problems like this are called parsing problems, perhaps you could google that for some ideas.

Comment: Does your input always have a sequence of letters followed by characters? Also, have you tried *any* approach at all, even if it's not simple? Please share that as well. You are much more likely to get help if you show that you tried something.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the input string `s` is always a sequence of a single alphabet, followed by a single digit, repeated; here's a solution with range-v3:

```
auto to_str = [](auto s) { return rv::repeat_n(s[0], s[1] - '0'); };

auto res = s | rv::chunk(2) | rv::transform(to_str) | rv::join | ranges::to<std::string>;
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hV9N2f).

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, I hope you find this helpful.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string convert_alphanumeric_to_alpha(string input){
    string new_string = "";
    string num_to_repeat = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
        if(isdigit(input[i]) && i < input.length() - 1){
            num_to_repeat += input[i];
        }else{
            if(i == input.length() - 1){
                num_to_repeat += input[i];
            }
            if(num_to_repeat != ""){
                int num = stoi(num_to_repeat) - 1;
                for(int j = 0; j < num; j++){
                    new_string += new_string[new_string.length() - 1];
                }
                num_to_repeat = "";
            }
            if(!isdigit(input[i])){
                new_string += input[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return new_string;
}

int main(){
    cout << convert_alphanumeric_to_alpha("a2b4c6d8e10f12") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output: aabbbbccccccddddddddeeeeeeeeeeffffffffffff